# Can a polyhedral cone have two opposing extreme rays?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

Does a line have two extreme rays or no extreme ray?

My main confusion is that there appear two  incompatible definitions of the extreme ray:

1. a nonzero element $x$ of a polyhedral cone is called an extreme ray if there are $n-1$ linearly independent constraints that are active at $x$.
2. An extreme direction is a direction that cannot be expressed as a positive combination of two distinct directions. See [source here](https://users.mai.liu.se/torla64/MAI0127/Sec_8.2_to_8.7_Fahimeh.pdf) and [here](https://homepages.rpi.edu/%7Emitchj/handouts/extreme/extreme.html).

Under the first definition, a line contains two opposing extreme rays. Under the second definition, however, a line has no extreme ray.

I want to know if it is possible to have two opposing extreme rays in the same polyhedral cone are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct directions are defined in the same page as a pair d1, d2 such that d1 is not a multiple of d2. Thus, in your example, d and -d are not distinct directions.

Comment: I think that definition of distinct direction $d^1 \ne k d^2$ is missing a qualification $k >0$. If $d$ and $-d$ were considered the same direction, then the ray $\{x~|~x=x^0 + \lambda d, \lambda \ge 0 \}$ and $\{x~|~x=x^0 - \lambda d, \lambda \ge 0 \}$ would be considered the same ray, which is obviously not true. (definition of the ray is also on the same page)